# Схема движения данных GPS от датчика до приложения на Android

Tags: java, android, gps, google-api

На какие этапы мы можем повлиять из кода в приложении?

1. В приложении мы берем GPS данные через `FusedLocationProviderApi`(это
   апи мы можем настроить под наши нужды, частота обновления и т.д.)
2. `FusedLocationProviderApi` берет `GPS` данные от `GoogleApiClient` (Его мы
       можем настраивать из нашего приложения, частоту обновления и т.д.?)
3. `GoogleApiClient` откуда берет данные? То откуда оно их берет можно
       настраивать из кода приложения?

Answer (score 2):

2. Можно [настраивать](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest)

   ```
   LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
           .setInterval() // частота
           .setPriority(); // приоритет получения данных (откуда берутся)
   ```
3. Данные берутся из любых доступных комбинациях GPS, Wi-fi, сотовых вышек (конкретно выбрать нельзя), в зависимости от выставленного приоритета:

   - `PRIORITY_NO_POWER`
   - `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER`
   - `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`
   - `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`

Comment: Во втором пункте я не уточнил, но спрашивал можно ли настроить googleApiClient, а Вы написали про  fusedLocationProviderApi, да?

Comment: @Gennady поясните, что значит настроить `googleApiClient`?

Comment: задать частоту обновления текущих координат, точность и т.д.